# Would you say "to face the screen of the smartphone downwards" or " to turn the smartphone upside down"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> **[right side up](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/right_1#right_idmg_6)** ​(North American English) with the top part turned to
>   the top; in the correct, normal position
>
> I dropped my toast, but luckily it fell right side up.

---

> **[upside down](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upside-down_1)**: ​in or into a position in which the top of something is where the bottom is normally found and the bottom is where the top
>   is normally found
>
> The canoe floated upside down on the lake.

---

> **[face](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/face_2)** [transitive, intransitive] to be opposite somebody/something; to
>   have your face or front pointing towards somebody/something or in a
>   particular direction
>
> face somebody/something She turned and faced him.
>
> Most of the rooms face the sea.
>
> They face each other across the aisle.
>
> face + adv./prep. The terrace faces south.
>
> a north-facing wall
>
> a south-east-facing garden
>
> to face outwards/inwards/upwards/downwards
>
> Lie with your palms facing upwards.
>
> Which direction are you facing?

---

Now, You just want your kid to listen to songs in Youtube videos and don't want him / her to look at the screen of the smartphone because it is not good for his / her eyes.

You don't want to leave your smartphone facing up like this
[image]

You want to leave your smartphone facing down like this

[image]

What would you say "**I'll face the screen of the smartphone downwards on the table**" or "**I'll turn the smartphone upside down, don't leave it right side up**"?

Comment: Place your smartphone face down.

Comment: By the way, buttered toast always falls buttered side down when you drop it on the floor. If you drop your toast and it ends up buttered side up, then you buttered your toast on the wrong side.

Comment: @user105719, so "face down" is an adverb in this case?

Comment: Adverb of manner, modifying the verb *place*. Once you've done that, you've got a *face-down* smartphone, and *face-down* is an adjective distinguishing your infernal device from all the other infernal devices that people have pressed to their faces

Comment: Why do you correctly use the obvious and idiomatic descriptions “facing up” and “facing down” and then only offer two strangely complex unidiomatic alternatives in your question?  (By the way, describing a phone as a “smartphone” all the time is a bit like saying “I parked my VW Golf Comfortline over there.” instead of saying “I parked my car over there.”)

Comment: @OrbitalAussie *Smartphone* is a generic name for a phone that can run apps. Do you think that's the only type of mobile phone in use?

Comment: @user105719.  Indeed. My point is that it is not idiomatic to use this (correct) name for the device in the context of ordinary informal conversation with “your kid” about “how to watch YouTube videos”. Perhaps you say to your partner, “Excuse me darling while I attend to the audible ringtones emitting from my smartphone indicating a call is coming through.” but I say “Sorry, I’ll just get the phone/mobile”.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie You have to say smartphone (or the brandname) in my house to distinguish my wife's phone from mine.